# Throwaway ticketing: picking optimal return date

Tags: air-travel, europe, tickets, canada, tips-and-tricks

I am flying from Madrid to Montreal (or possibly Stockholm to Montreal) in early January and single tickets are much more expensive than returns, so I am thinking of utilizing the throwaway ticket ploy. Is there any website out there that can find the optimal return date (i.e. the return date that gives the lowest total price)? Or does it usually not matter?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE!  Specifying where exactly you're flying from/to would be helpful.

Comment: For your specific search, I randomly tried a one-way Stockholm-Montreal in January and found a ticket for 360 euros. I don't think it is easy to find cheaper. But give a try to Icelandair or Air Transat, they are airlines offering reasonably priced one-way transatlantic flights.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of any fare search engine that targets precisely this option, but quite a few let you search date ranges, eg. [Adioso](http://adioso.com) and [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com).  [Rome2Rio](http://rome2rio.com) is also handy for getting a feel of possible prices, and it's the only search engine I know of that will actually let you search for "[Europe to Canada](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Europe/Canada)"!  (Best offer today: Stuttgart to Montreal, $490.)

In general, **3-4 weeks** is the sweet spot for cheapest ticket length.  Less than 14 days, and you'll start hitting some fares' minimum stay requirements; over 30 days, and you'll start hitting some fares' maximum stay requirements.  Obviously this depends on airline, destination, time of year, phase of moon etc, but since there's not much going on anywhere in late Jan, this will likely work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Kiwi offers this search option with their "Anytime" return search filter. Though note that for this particular route a one-way ticket is cheaper than a return fare.

[image]

Kiwi will also automatically suggest the throwaway ticketing hack where it does make sense:

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with Kiwi in any way.